# Submit multiple entries to database, from an array, in Rails on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm trying to submit multiple entries into the database from an array.  So, I create multiple new entries and store them in an array.  In the view, I have a form of checkboxes for the user to check which ones he/she wants to add to the database.  Upon clicking submit, I would like to add each of these forms to the database all in on shot. Here is the code:

Controller:

```
class EventsBoysController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @season = find_season
    @meet = find_meet(@season)
    @athletes_boys = current_coach.athletes.where(boy: true)
    @events_boys = []
    @athletes_boys.each do |athlete|
      @events_boys << @meet.events_boys.new(:athlete_id => athlete.id)
    end
    @events = ["400 IH", "100", "1600", "400", "110 HH", "800", "3200", "200"]
  end

  def create
    debugger
    @season = find_season
    @meet = find_meet(@season)
    @events_boys = @meet.events_boys.create(events_boy_permit)
    # debugger
    if @events_boys.save
      redirect_to @events_boys, notice: 'Season was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  private
  def find_season
    Season.find(params[:season_id])
  end

  def find_meet season
    season.meets.find(params[:meet_id])
  end

  def events_boy_permit
    params.require(:events_boy).permit(:season_id, :meet_id, :athlete_id, :boys_400_m_im, :boys_1600_m, :boys_400_m, :boys_110_m_hh, :boys_800_m, :boys_3200_m, :boys_200_m, :boys_100_m, :time_400_m_im, :time_1600_m, :time_400_m, :time_110_m_hh, :time_800_m, :time_3200_m, :time_200_m, :time_100_m, :place_400_m_im, :place_1600_m, :place_400_m, :place_110_m_hh, :place_800_m, :place_3200_m, :place_200_m, :place_100_m)
  end

end
```

View:

```
<h1><%= "Create new events for the boys for #{@meet.name}" %></h1>

<table id="events-table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <th><%= event %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>

  <% @events_boys.each do |event| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= Athlete.find_by_id(event.athlete_id).name %></td>
      <%= form_for [@season, @meet, event], :html => { :mulitpart => true } do |f| %>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_400_m_im %></td>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_100_m %></td>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_1600_m  %></td>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_400_m  %></td>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_110_m_hh %></td>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_800_m %></td>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_3200_m  %></td>

        <td><%= f.check_box :boys_200_m  %></td>

        <td><%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn' %></td>

      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var athletes = new Array();
  var arrayInAthletes = new Array();
  element = document.getElementById("events-table");
  var athletesArray = element.children[0].children
  for (i=1; i < athletesArray.length; i++) {
    var rowArray = athletesArray[i].children;
    arrayInAthletes = [];
    arrayInAthletes[0] = rowArray[0].innerText;
    var sum = 0;

    for (j=1; j < rowArray.length; j++) {
      var checkBox = rowArray[j].children[0];
      var checkedValue = $('#'+checkBox.id+':checked').val();
      if (checkedValue === "1") {
        arrayInAthletes[sum+1] = rowArray[j].children[0].id;
        sum += 1;
      }
    }

    athletes[i-1] = arrayInAthletes;

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like the code below (needs to be adapted to your example).

```
Contact.create([
  {first_name: 'Ryan', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'ryan@smith.com'}, 
  {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', email: 'john@doe.com'}
])
```

All you need to do is put your data into an array of hashes. Each hash is an object you want to save. This will do a batch insert, which is what I think you want.

You will need to pull the values for checked/unchecked from your params since that is where they are passed to your controller. Cycle through that hash and perform your logic on that.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I would like to do.  The only thing is, how do apply this my checkboxes that I have on my view?  That part is what I am having trouble understanding how to do.